# How to detect that Indirect GLX is needed but disabled?

Tags: opengl, x11, glx

For a few years now, indirect GLX (IGLX) has been disabled by default in `xorg` and other X Servers.  I'm writing an application that will use OpenGL if available, but can fall back to other graphics if it is not.  Is there a standard way to detect that it is going to fail, other than trying it and responding to the errors?

My current test (written about 20 years ago) just checks if `XOpenDisplay` and `glXQueryExtension` work, but that's not sufficient:  things fail later when calling `glXCreateContext` and other functions.

I'd prefer not to try to open a window and check for success, because at the time I want to do the test I don't know if the user is going to need one.  My preference is to do an invisible test at startup so I can warn the user that they're going to be using the backup graphics methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a OpenGL context with GLX doesn't require a window. Neiter `glxCreateContext` nor `glxCreateNewContext` take a drawable paramter. And even if they did, you can create a window without ever mapping it, i.e. make it visible, or even trigger some action from the window manager.

In X11 creating windows is a rather cheap operation, especially if the initial size of the window is 0×0 and the window is never mapped. You can still perform the whole range of X11 and GLX operations.

The upshot of all of this is, that to test if the OpenGL capabilities are available, the usual approach is to actually attempt to create an window and OpenGL context with the desired attributes and see, if this succeeds.

Since the X11 resources used for probing don't have to be mapped, this will not create any visible output; and apart from constantly polling the X server for the window tree, not even a window manager will take notice (since this depends on mapping the window).

Of course to keep thins cheap and fast, such tests should be programmed directly against X11 / Xlib, without any toolkits inbetween (since GLX is written against Xlib, even if Xcb is used, you'll have to use Xlib, for at least that part, but you'd have to do that anyway).

Comment: In my case I only want to create drawable windows, but I want to predict whether that will succeed without actually doing it.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @user2554330: What do you imagine you'd gain from trying to "predict" this? Just create the window, go through all the motions to setup the context and what not else. And only if all of that succeeds and meets your expectations, as the finishing touch *map* it. If you figure that something isn't right, just don't map it, and follow the fallback path. Without mapping the window, it will never show up anywhere. Not even the window manager will take notice of its existence (without actively polling the X server).

Comment: The most important gain is that on startup I can tell the user something like:  "Your system needs indirect GLX, but you have it disabled.  Go to this web page for a discussion of this issue."  I'd rather not tell the user this after they've invested effort into designing the final result.  Another gain is that I don't need to undo all the setup that was done for nothing.  I'm writing in C, so backing out is fairly painful and error prone.  Finally, the errors I'm seeing are very generic, things like "integer parameter out of range for operation".

Comment: @user2554330: Creating a test window is not expensive. This is not like creating an expensive toolkit backed window. Just create a simple, disposable test window, that you'll throw away afterwards. This is your test how to do this. If this fails to meet your expectations, you can show the user the message. There's absolutely nothing expensive about creating a window. Windows are cheap, especially unmapped ones.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll try.

Comment: This seems to work.  I still get the `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found` and `libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast` messages on the console, but I can live with that.  Could you move a summary of your comments into the answer, and I'll accept it?